# Передача данных из одной формы в другую

Tags: python, django

Есть заполненная форма, необходимо данные формы передать в другую форму и в другой добавить пару полей hidden. Кто подскажет как с помощью Django сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Неоднозначный вопрос. «Форма» — понятие растяжимое. Больше конкретики бы.

Если надо потом показать вторую форму (которая с дополнительными полями), то, например, как-то так:

```
# Первая форма
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.CharField(...)
    bar = forms.CharField(...)

# Вторая форма добавляет скрытое поле (для простоты примера, одно)
class ExtendedSomeForm(SomeForm):
    baz = forms.CharField(..., widget=forms.HiddenInput())

# Пример вьюшки
def process_someform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Принимаем первую форму
        someform = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if someform.is_valid:
            # Форма валидна, берем копию ее данных, …
            extform_data = copy.copy(someform.cleaned_data)
            # … добавляем значения для скрытых полей, …
            extform_data["baz"] = "baz_data"
            # … и делаем на основе этого вторую форму.
            extform = ExtendedSomeForm(initial=extform_data)
            return render_to_response("ext_someform.html", {"form": extform}, ...)
    else:
        someform = SomeForm()
    return render_to_response("someform.html", {"form": someform}, ...)
```

(Код не проверял, писался прямо в браузере, но общая суть должна быть верна.)

А если, например, речь о том, что откуда-то приходит кусок HTML с формой (тоже «форма») и надо в нее добавить полей — это совсем другая ситуация. Самое простое решение «в лоб», тогда будет тривиальным:

```
# from django.utils.html import escape
hidden_inputs = '<input type="hidden" name="baz" value="%s">' % escape(baz)
new_form_html = form_html.replace("</form>", hidden_inputs + "</form>")
```

Сложнее — скормить данные lxml или BeatifulSoup и поработать с деревом. В случае, если надо получить значения из HTML'я с формой, это единственный разумный вариант (кроме парсинга регэкспами, который скоро непременно сломается).

Уточняйте вопрос, если что.